# vnc server in java , is there such thing ? opensource?

Tags: java, vnc-server

i didnt found any vnc server written in java is there any change there is no such thing ? 
i mean free and open source ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this? [vncjlgpl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vncjlgpl/)

Comment: Doesn't work at all for me. And I can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[Ajax VNC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ajaxvnc/?source=typ_redirect) is an alternative. It works even behind a firewall or proxy and it's pure HTTP.